# Laravel - Prevent duplicate script tags when using partials/modals

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I have a few update forms that exist on multiple pages. To reduce workload, I have built these forms as partials/modals that can be @included when needed.  Some of the forms utilize a mask.js so I also include an @parent for 'scripts' to include the  tag.

It works, but I think I may be attempting to load external JS multiple times if two of the forms use the mask.js and are included in the same view blade.

For example:

Main Page

```
@include('partials.newdate')
@include('partials.olddate')
```

partials/newdate.blade.php

```
@section('scripts')
@parent
<script src="/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
@stop
```

partials/olddate.blade.php

```
@section('scripts')
@parent
<script src="/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
@stop
```

both of the partials need this script, but I also would like to avoid loading it on all pages to reduce load times.

Is there something I can do to "check" for jquery.mask.min.js before laravel adds it to the script section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the once directive

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#the-once-directive

```
@once
    @push('scripts')
        <script>
            // Your custom JavaScript...
        </script>
    @endpush
@endonce
```